# Python Requests Library vs. Casperjs html output?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, casperjs

I was playing around with scraping today and noticed two different outputs of html using the requests and casperjs librarys

The actual html that can be seen in firebug or browser source is:

```
 <td align="left">
 Miles with Expiration Deferred Through
                     Jan 22, 2016
</td>
```

Casperjs outputs the same:

```
<td align="left">
 Miles with Expiration Deferred Through
                     Jan 22, 2016
</td>
```

Requests outputs something slightly different.

```
<td align="left">
 Miles with Expiration Deferred Through

     Fri Jan 22 00:00:00 CST 2016
</td>
```

I'm just using basic request logic below.

```
 r = requests.get(url)
 html = r.text
```

What is going on here?  As I write this I'm thinking maybe the cookie data is not set correctly using the requests library and it's sending back slightly different data/format?  With Caspjer it's all high level and I don't touch the cookies.  Any ideas?

Comment: The difference is probably in the headers. Here are the [default headers](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/d33ce49aaa46c855458582f338a6e2039d428bee/requests/utils.py#L553) that `requests` uses.

Comment: I tried 2 different user-agent strings.  I am getting the same result. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely it is being formatted by JavaScript in CasperJS, whereas Requests is showing you raw data from the HTTP request (with no JavaScript executed against it).

Comment: I think you are on to something here.  I need to look into it more. thanks for the idea :)